# Apache Camel and Netty as a TCP sticky balancer

Tags: tcp, apache-camel, netty, load-balancing

I'm trying to load balance TCP connections over multiple backend servers via Apache Camel and Netty.

I want to make each connection to the backend mapped to each connection to Camel. Something like this:

1. Client connects to Camel.
2. Camel selects a backend server and connects to it.
3. Client sends something to Camel.
4. Camel sends it to the associated backend server.
5. Backend server replies to Camel.
6. Camel sends it back to client.
7. ...

My protocol is stateful and the connection between client and Camel will stay open. I also need messages starting from backend and going to client.

So far, so good. This is working quite nice.
My problem starts when I connect a new client that goes to the same backend server, it looks like Camel reuses the connection that is already open, for the backend server it looks like the first client sent the message, it doesn't receive a new connection request.

I've looked at Apache Camel Netty Component documentation and didn't find anything to configure this behaviour.

Is it possible to do this?

*Sidenote*: I'm using Camel because I need to inspect the messages in the protocol to select a backend server, *i.e.* I need a custom loadbalancing strategy. The problem occurs using any loadbalancing strategy provided by Camel, so it's not related to my code.

Answer (score 0):

Camel has a [sticky](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/processor/loadbalancer/StickyLoadBalancer.html) [loadbalancer](http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html), you just need to setup an expression to tell camel to decide which object hashcode it need to be use.

```
from("direct:start").loadBalance().
            sticky(header("source")).to("mock:x", "mock:y", "mock:z");
```

Comment: I've done that already. This is working fine. The problem is that a new connection to camel reuses the same connection to the backend.

Comment: yeah, camel-netty is try to reuse the connection as possible. If the connection is active, it doesn't start a new connection for it. If you want to change this behavior, we need to implement a new object pool inside of camel-netty producer to star a new connection if the proxy client is different.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the tip. I think Camel can't do two-way communication also. So it would need more changes, and maybe this is not even the point of Camel. So I'm going the road to code the entire router and balancer on my own.